# How do I write this Android App? Automatic change of Audio Output Mode

Tags: android, audio, output, hdmi

My device is an Android MiniTV mk808c.

The device defaults the Audio Output to audio_hdmi. 
I need the device to default to audio_codec OR change to audio_codec automatically.
I can do this manually via a menu under settings->sound->audio output

From what I understand "audio output mode is a setting - audio.routing. It accepts the values 2 (CODEC), 1024 (HDMI) and 4096 (S/PDIF). "

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need to write a one line app or if you have any other idea?

Comment: Does anyone know existing app to set default audio device on boot/once?

Answer (score 1):

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setParameters("audio_devices_out_active=AUDIO_CODEC");
```

Comment: Even though this code might be obvious to the experienced user you could make this post more informative by providing a brief explanation.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Would you be able to provide a bit more guidance than just the code? More details on writing good answers can be found [in the help on "How to Answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setParameters("audio_devices_out_active=AUDIO_CODEC");

**The above code is correct. But it needs the below permission to work in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```